# Why my currently add listbox item is not accessible?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox named as EntrylistBox. I am adding items in it and now i want to access ui container of last
added items but its giving null. While i can access

> EntrylistBox.Items.Count - 2

index but 
last index is returning null , now I'm wondering why? Any help

I'm using following code to access ui container of last added item in listbox:

```
 EntrylistBox.Items.Add(entry);
 var container= EntrylistBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(EntrylistBox.Items[EntrylistBox.Items.Count - 1]) as FrameworkElement;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `UIContainer` be the listbox? Due to it contains the item? Or what container do you want to get?

Comment: I want to access UIcontainer of particular listboxitem. currently by using this code i can get all item except last item added. now i guess my currently added entry is not visible yet so i cant access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemContainer will only created for the items which are all in the view due to virtualization. So you can't able to get the ItemContainer if the item is not in view.

Regards,
Riyaj Ahamed I

Comment: Yeah! item is not added in view. anyways I solved my problem by another approach. Anyways thanks @Riyaj